# How can I assign a value to KMutableProperty parameter?

Tags: kotlin

In a method I would like to receive KMutableProperty as parameter and assign a value to it.

Another question is what is the correct way of passing a parameter into such a method.

Basically I would like to have something like that:

```
class MyBinder {
  ...

  fun bind(property: KMutableProperty<Int>): Unit {
     property.set(internalIntValue)
  }
}
```

And then call it in another class

```
  myBinder.bind(this::intProperty)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin 1.0 does not allow the `this::intProperty` syntax, but this is being worked currently and will be available soon as a part of the early access preview of 1.1 ([issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6947), [KEEP proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/5)).

With this in mind, I'd consider doing what you're describing in another way, for example making `bind` accept a lambda which sets the property:

```
class MyBinder {
    fun bind(setProperty: (Int) -> Unit) {
        setProperty(internalIntValue)
    }
}

...

myBinder.bind { intProperty = it }
```

Anyway, to answer your question about setting the value of `KMutableProperty`: to set the value of some property or, technically speaking, to invoke the property setter, you should know its arity, or the number of parameters that property (and its getter/setter) accepts. Properties declared in a file do not accept any parameters, member properties and extension properties require one parameter (the receiver instance), while member properties which are also extensions take two parameters. These kinds of properties are represented by the following subtypes of `KMutableProperty` respectively: `KMutableProperty0`, `KMutableProperty1`, `KMutableProperty2` -- the number means the arity and their generic type parameters mean the types of receivers. Each of these property types has a `set` method with the corresponding parameters. Some examples:

```
fun setValue(property: KMutableProperty0<Int>, value: Int) {
    property.set(value)
}

fun setValue(property: KMutableProperty1<SomeType, Int>, instance: SomeType, value: Int) {
    property.set(instance, value)
}
```

Note that there's no `set` (or `get`) method in the abstract `KMutableProperty` interface precisely because it's impossible to declare it, not knowing the number of required receiver parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Alexander's answer, you can try something like this:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty

class Binder {
  val internalIntValue = 10

  fun bind(self: Any, aProperty: KMutableProperty<Int>) {
    aProperty.setter.call(self, internalIntValue)
  }
}

class Foo {
  var bar = 1

  fun changeBar() {
    Binder().bind(this, Foo::bar)
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val foo = Foo()

  assert(1 == foo.bar)

  foo.changeBar()

  assert(10 == foo.bar)
}
```

A more robust/safe way to do the same thing:

```
fun <T> bind(self: T, aProperty: KMutableProperty1<T, Int>) {
  aProperty.set(self, internalIntValue)
}
```

My thanks to Alexander. His answer gave me the previous idea.